# Extracting specific portions of data/txt and organising them in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write code that is able to find three different variables and their values and save them, will ideally output to txt or csv later

For example

```
Random irrelevant line
Results are Alpha: = 10 Beta: = 5 Charlie: = 4
Random irrelevant line
Random irrelevant line
```

So my code needs to:
Find the info among the log
Recognise that "Alpha" "Beta" and "Charlie" are different variables
Connect their values with (e.g. know that Aplha=10)

I have no idea how to approach this
I successfully did a pretty simple script to pull the entire 4th (in the example) line out and any others that had the variables, but just don't know where to go from there

I'm a beginner btw

Comment: Are variables always integers ?

Comment: If value is a float or int, use regex?

Comment: Always going to be Alpha, Beta, Charlie with values between 2 and 4 digits

Comment: I don't know what that means Josip Juros

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do so:

```
import re

text = """
Random irrelevant line
Results are Alpha: = 10 Beta: = 5 Charlie: = 4
Random irrelevant line
Random irrelevant line
"""


variables = re.findall(r"(\w+): = (\w+)", text)
```

Values are stored in a list as string, we can then use dict comprehension to convert every numbers to integers.

```
variables = {key: int(item) if item.isdigit() else item for key, item in variables}

print(variables)
```

---

**Output:**

```
{'Alpha': 10, 'Beta': 5, 'Charlie': 4}
```

---

- `(\w+)`: Matches any word character between one and unlimited times, as much as possible.
- `: =` : Matches `: =` .

Comment: Thank you but for some reason it's just "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"